# Writing a function that reproduces the same output as the "separate" dplyr function in R

Tags: r, function, dplyr

I am doing an exercise to practice writing functions. The problem is asking for my function to reproduce the same output as the `separate` function in `dplyr`.

I have the following data frame:

```
df <- data.frame(dates = c("2005-06-29", "2005-07-16", "2005-12-01"), 
                  values = c("F:62:130", "F:68:149", "M:68:160"),
                  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

I want to separate the "values" column into three separate columns (split at the colon) and drop the "values" column in the final data frame to look like:

```
dates        gender  ht   wt
1 2005-06-29      F  62  130
2 2005-07-16      F  68  149
3 2005-12-01      M  68  160
```

The problem I'm running into is naming the new columns in my function. This is what I have so far:

```
  into <- c() 
  names(into) <- c(a = "", b = "", c = "")
```

But when I run my new function, I'm getting an error that I'm attempting `to set an attribute on NULL.`

When I remove the into/names(into) stuff, I get the following (with the wrong new column names):

```
dates            values   a  b   c
1 2005-06-29   F:62:130   F 62  130
2 2005-07-16   F:68:149   F 68  149
3 2005-12-01   M:68:160   F 68  160
```

How do I create an `into` argument in the function that lets me name the columns whatever I want?

Comment: I think the error was from one my comments in the function. Changed it. @akrun

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `base R`, we can use `substring`

```
transform(df, a = substr(values, 1, 1), 
         b = substring(values, 3, 4),
          wt = substring(values, 6))
```

---

Or another easier option is to read with `read.table` specifying the `sep` as `:` and create columns on the original dataset either by assignment or `cbind`ing

```
df[c('a', 'b', 'wt')] <- read.table(text = df$values,  sep=":",  header = FALSE)
df
#       dates   values a  b  wt
#1 2005-06-29 F:62:130 F 62 130
#2 2005-07-16 F:68:149 F 68 149
#3 2005-12-01 M:68:160 M 68 160
```

---

The OP's function can be changed to

```
myfunc <- function(df, colnum = 2, into = c("a", "b", "c"), sep = ":") {

  # Use "colnum" to access the specified column of "df"
  j1 <- colnum
  colnum <- df[ , colnum]

  # Split "df" using the specified separator 
  storage <- strsplit(colnum, split = sep)


  # Take/second/third elements and store it into the above vectors
  a <- sapply(storage, function(x) x[1])
  b <- sapply(storage, function(x) x[2])
  c <- sapply(storage, function(x) x[3])

  out <- cbind(df, setNames(list(a, b, c), into))
  out[setdiff(names(out), names(df)[j1])]

}

myfunc(df)
#.       dates a  b   c
#1 2005-06-29 F 62 130
#2 2005-07-16 F 68 149
#3 2005-12-01 M 68 160



myfunc(df, into = c('a1', 'b1', 'c1'))
#      dates a1 b1  c1
#1 2005-06-29  F 62 130
#2 2005-07-16  F 68 149
#3 2005-12-01  M 68 160
```

Comment: Is there an option to drop a column with `cbind`? For instance, I want to drop the "values" column in my final output.

Comment: It's the `colnum` argument in my function. I tried `cbind(df[ ,-colnum], setNames(list(a, b, c), into))`

Comment: @user12310746 based on the example you showed,  it is working for me

Comment: @user12310746 Here, the `colnum` is already updated.  Please check my comment  earlier.  Also, this won't work, instead you out[[j1]] <- NULL

Comment: @user12310746 suppose you have a column name or number stored as `v1 <- 2` and then you do `$`,i.e. `mtcars$v1 <- 20` it creates 'v1' column, similarly if the 'v1' is already a column name and you are eassigning to NULL, it rremoves 'v1' and not the second column name.  For that you need `[[` i.e. `mtcars[[v1]]` to evaluate the value stored in 'v1' and not the literal v1

Answer (score 0):

Here is a base R solution

```
dfout <- cbind(df,`colnames<-`(do.call(rbind,strsplit(df$values,":")),c("a","b","wt")))
```

which gives

```
> dfout
       dates   values a  b  wt
1 2005-06-29 F:62:130 F 62 130
2 2005-07-16 F:68:149 F 68 149
3 2005-12-01 M:68:160 M 68 160
```